# How to create rectangular box around edittext in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

I want to create an attractive UI. I want to create a rectangular box around the edittext. How can I make it?

Comment: You can use a custom drawable background?

Comment: Use a TextInputLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the standard `TextInputLayout` with an OutlinedBox style:

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:text="TEXT"/>

     </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

You can use the `boxStrokeWidth` and `boxStrokeColor` to change width and color.

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
         app:boxStrokeColor="@color/xxxx"
         app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

create a drawable with shape rectangle and apply background to edit text

```
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4e555f" />
    </shape>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_mobile_no"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="drawable name"/>
```